# The differential of the exponential map on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $exp_{x}: T_{x}M \to M$ the usual exponential map. It is an important fact that $D_{0}exp_{x}(v) = v$ for any $v \in T_{0}(T_{x}M)$.

The proof goes like this:

$D_{0} exp_{x}(v) = \frac{d}{dt} exp_{x}(tv)|_{t = 0} =  \gamma(t)'|_{t = 0} = v$, where $\gamma(t)$ is the geodesic starting at $v$. I am struggling to understand this proof because I find it hard to interpret $\frac{d}{dt} exp_{x}(tv)|_{t = 0}$. Is it supposed to be understood as $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{exp_{x}(tv) - exp_{x}(0)}{t}?$ This difference expression does not make sense since we cannot take difference on a manifold without extra structure.

I guess my problem is most of the texts I encountered tend to treat calculations like this like they are in the Euclidean space rather than on a manifold. I suppose it should be correct to do so, but is it trivially true without any justification?

The way I would prove this is to take $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$, and try to figure out what is the action of $D_{0}exp_{x}(v)$ on $f$, but none of the reference I find take this approach.

Comment: Observe that the map $t \mapsto \exp_x(tv)$ is a parameterized curve in $M$. So $\frac{d}{dt}\exp_x(tv) = c'(t)$ is the velocity of the curve $c$. You should have already learned how to calculate the velocity of a parameterized curve in a manifold. In particular, in local coordinates, it really is the limit of the difference quotient you wrote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compute ${\rm d}(\exp_x)_0(v)$, you compute $$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|_{t=0} \exp_x(\alpha(t))$$where $\alpha \colon (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to T_xM$ is any curve with $\alpha(0) = 0$ and $\alpha'(0) = v$.  How to understand the above derivative? Read it as the composition it is: $\exp_x\circ \alpha \colon (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M$. In other words, this is just a particular curve in the manifold $M$, and you should be comfortable taking velocities of curves. The result will not depend on the choice of $\alpha$, so one takes $\alpha(t) = tv$, meaning that we look at the curve $t \mapsto \exp_x(tv)$. This is precisely the geodesic starting at $0$ with intitial velocity $v$. But the derivative $$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|_{t=0} \exp_x(tv)$$is the initial velocity of this curve! Which you know to be $v$. Thus $${\rm d}(\exp_x)_0(v) = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|_{t=0}\exp_x(tv) = v.$$

---

In more detail, what is the derivative of a curve $\gamma\colon I \to M$? For each $t \in I$, you expect to have $\gamma'(t) \in T_{\gamma(t)}M$, right? And what is a tangent vector at $\gamma(t)$? It is a derivation acting on germs of smooth functions at $\gamma(t)$. How is the derivation $\gamma'(t)$ defined? Simple: take $f \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ and set $\gamma'(t)f = (f\circ \gamma)'(t)$. The derivative on the right side here is a usual derivative you learnt in single-variable calculus, because the composition $f\circ \gamma$ is a function $I \to \Bbb R$, i. e., a real-valued function defined on some interval. Once you understand things like the chain rule, one deals with $\gamma'(t)$ itself without going back every time to what $\gamma'(t)f$ is.

Comment: This is one equivalent definition of differential: $\varphi:M\to N$, $v \in T_pM$, $${\rm d}\varphi_p(v)=\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|_{t=0}(\varphi\circ \alpha)'(t)\in T_{\varphi(p)}N,$$where $\alpha$ is a curve in $M$ with $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=v$. I'll leave it as an exercise to show that this definition coincides with what you have there. Use that $\gamma'(t)f = (f\circ \gamma)'(0)$ taking $\gamma = \varphi \circ \alpha$ in $N$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (even though it wasn't my question). However, I'm struggling with a relevant question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459046/how-do-we-calculate-the-gradient-of-this-function-defined-using-the-riemannian-l. I'd appreciate it if you could please answer?